# Concept about anonymous function and invoke in javascript

Tags: javascript, invoke

Now I have to solve a exercise in the exercise from freecodecamp. 
The outcome are expected as follows:

`addTogether(2, 3)` should return `5`.

`addTogether(2)(3)` should return `5`.

`addTogether("This is sth")` should return `undefined`.

`addTogether(2, "3")` should return `undefined`.

`addTogether(2)([3])` should return `undefined`.

And by referring to some suggested solutions, one of the solutions is like:

```
function add(){
   var args= [].slice.call(arguments);

   if (!args.every(function(argument){return typeof argument === 'number';})){
    return undefined;
   }

   if(args.length === 2){
    return args[0] + args[1]; 
   } else {
    var a = args[0];
    var addOne = function(b){
      return add(a,b);
    };
    return addOne; 
   }
  return false 
}

add(2)(3)
```

In here, I am not really sure, why in the variable addOne, the anonymous function will successfully capture the the value in the second  brackets, after calling the first value before?

I seek for the information about JavaScript function invocation, but still do not 100% sure why...

Edited: 
With the features of closure, because I have already extracted the first parentheses, the next closure i.e the function, will automatically take the second input? And in this case, if I want to do addTogether(2)(3)(4)(5) , then I can do that by creating closures within different parentheses e.g

```
 var a = args[0];
  var addOne = function(b){
    var addTwo = function(c){
     var addThree = function(d){
       return a+b+c+d;
     }
   }      
};
```

Do I understand in the correct sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In here, I am not really sure, why in the variable addOne, the
>   anonymous function will successfully capture the the value in the
>   second brackets, after calling the first value before?

Because, when you say, `addTogether(2)`, it means you're calling a function and passing it an integer 2, and when you say `addTogether(2)(3)`, it means, you're calling a function and passing it an integer 2, which is then returning a function, to which you're passing the integer 3.

So, when the code says `return addOne`, it is returning the function which is called with the second parentheses, `(3)`, so `addTogether` gets the value 2 and the return of addTogether, which is `addOne` gets the value 3.

Comment: Many thanks! That means, with the features of closure, because I have already extracted the first parentheses, the next closure i.e the function, will automatically take the second input? And in this case, if I want to do addTogether(2)(3)(4)(5) , then I can do that by creating closures within different parentheses?

Comment: @PakHangLeung Thats true. Although it is not a good pattern to follow, but for research and learning, this is great.